# Preload a scene ? Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a platformer game, and my scene has like 400 differents node so when I go from the main menu to my scene

```
self.removeAllChildren()
```

`if let nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"){
      let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 3)
      view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
   }`

I have a 3s freeze before my scene apear.

My question is: is there a way to preload the scene while I'm in the main menu to avoid this 3s freeze (which can increase if I add some nodes)

[image: Here is the scene I want to load (don't know if it could help)]

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add nodes while not being on the main thread. But it's just adding the nodes that takes 3 seconds or there is more going on? Wat do the loops look like you use to add the items? Perhaps you could create them first asynchronously then *only* add them on the main thread when everything is ready?

Comment: I think I was wrong. I try to go to the scene without any code in it (no code in update func, no code in didMove func) and it took 3s too. So it seems it's loading the GameScene.sks wich took so long

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint here:
    if let nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"){    it will take 3 seconds to go to the next step? Also the duration is 3. what happens if you lower that or remove it?

Comment: A couple of questions: __1)__ Why this? `self.removeAllChildren()` __2)__ If you remove the transition (`let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 3)`) what happen?

Comment: @DepartamentoB I tried, and yes, the 3s freeze are between if let nextScene and let transition.   Also the duration of 3s is because I tried first with 1s and it didn't appear at all.

Comment: @appzYourLife 1) to remove the childs from the actual scene. I use it to reload scene when player die, but it seems not usefull here. 2-3) without transition I have also a freeze

Comment: removeallchildren is not needed, when you swap screens your scene will deinit  What is going on in your didMoveToView?  400 nodes created in your sks will not cause a delay.  Your nodes are created prior to presenting your scene.  Finally, you can add nodes on the background thread as long as you are adding it to a node on the same thread.